# Microsoft DI Container _transientDisposables not disposed (memory leak)

Tags: c#, memory, dependency-injection, ioc-container

We are using ASP.NET MS DI container for our asp.net Sitecoer MVC CMS web application.

We noticed that memory growing rapidly during load test. Looking a memory dump I noticed that _transientDisposable is holding way too many IDisposable collection. Should MS DI dispose those collection upon GC collection? Below is the container registeration.

[image]

Questions I've:

All my services are registered as SCOPED (per request).

Why is ServiceProvider not disposing the IDosable collection. Should MS Container dispose those collection upon request end.

Read these threads and didn't made too much sense. Is it a bug with MS DI or something that I'm not doing right:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5496 https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/456

Answer (score 4):

This is probably caused by you (or some third party) resolving object graphs directly from the root `IServiceProvider`, instead of resolving it from an `IServiceScope`. Disposable transients are referenced inside the scope so they can be disposed when the scope ends. When you resolve from the root container, however, the root container becomes *the scope*, and those disposable transients are referenced inside the root container, and will only get removed when the root container is disposed. The root container, however, only gets disposed when the application ends.

Long story short: Never resolve from the root container when using MS.DI.

Comment: thanks. Is there way to tell where in code we are resolving from root? The detailed code snippet is on this question

Comment: No, there isn't. You'll have to debug.

Comment: Is it necessary to  CreateScope and wrap within using block?

Comment: It is, if you don't have an active scope.